# C++ What using for lexicographical_compare?

Tags: c++, function, lexicographic

I wan to user the function lexicographical_compare in algorithms library in c++.

But I do not know what to write as far as the using statement. For example

```
using std::lexicographical_compare ??
```

How can I figure this out for my self in the future?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just do

```
 using std::lexicographical_compare;
```

and then (copied from [SGI STL Doc](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/lexicographical_compare.html))

```
int main()
{
  int A1[] = {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 3};
  int A2[] = {3, 1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7};
  int A3[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  int A4[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

  const int N1 = sizeof(A1) / sizeof(int);
  const int N2 = sizeof(A2) / sizeof(int);
  const int N3 = sizeof(A3) / sizeof(int);
  const int N4 = sizeof(A4) / sizeof(int);

  bool C12 = lexicographical_compare(A1, A1 + N1, A2, A2 + N2);
  bool C34 = lexicographical_compare(A3, A3 + N3, A4, A4 + N4);

  cout << "A1[] < A2[]: " << (C12 ? "true" : "false") << endl;
  cout << "A3[] < A4[]: " << (C34 ? "true" : "false") << endl;
}
```

Alternatively

```
// no using statement

int main()
{
   //... same as above
   bool C12 = std::lexicographical_compare(A1, A1 + N1, A2, A2 + N2);
   bool C34 = std::lexicographical_compare(A3, A3 + N3, A4, A4 + N4);
   //... same as above
}
```

To know yourself in the future, read a C++ book (e.g. Stroustrup's "The C++ Programming Language") from cover to cover.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is fine - you will also need to include the algorithm header:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

As to how to find out these things for yourself, I strongly recommend getting a copy of [The C++ Standard Library](http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Usage example, from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lexicographical_compare-in-cpp/

```
// helper function to convert all into lower case:
bool comp (char s1, char s2) {
    return tolower(s1)<tolower(s2);
}

void test_lexicographical_compare(){
    // initializing char arrays
    char one[] = "geeksforgeeks";
    char two[] = "gfg";

    // using lexicographical_compare for checking
    // is "one" is less than "two"
    if( lexicographical_compare(one, one+13, two, two+3)) {
        cout << "geeksforgeeks is lexicographically less than gfg"<<endl;

    }
    else {
        cout << "geeksforgeeks is not lexicographically less than gfg"<<endl;

    }

    // now two = "Gfg";
    strncpy(two, "Gfg", 3);
    // using lexicographical_compare for checking
    // is "one" is less than "two"
    // returns true this time as all converted into lowercase
    if( lexicographical_compare(one, one+13, two, two+3, comp)){
        cout << "geeksforgeeks is lexicographically less  ";
        cout << "than Gfg( case-insensitive )"<<endl;

    }
    else{
        cout << "geeksforgeeks is not lexicographically less ";
        cout<< "than Gfg( case-insensitive )"<<endl;
    }

}
```

output:

```
geeksforgeeks is lexicographically less than gfg

geeksforgeeks is lexicographically less  than Gfg( case-insensitive )
```